# MySQL Relative ranking of values in one column for all occurrences of a given key

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for some basic direction on how where to start looking to try and rank rows of a common key in a query.

Imagine I have a table like this:

```
user_id | account_id | score
1         A            10
1         B            20
2         C            10
2         D            20
2         E            30
```

What I'm hoping to do is add a rank column for relative to each `user_id` where the highest score gets the top rank:

```
user_id | account_id | score | rank
1         A            10      2
1         B            20      1
2         C            10      3
2         D            20      2
2         E            30      1
```

Just looking for some basic direction in terms of which way to head :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery

```
select 
*,
(select count(1)+1 from your_table b where a.user_id=b.user_id and a.score<b.score) as rank
from your_table a
```

Output

```
1   A   10  2
1   B   20  1
2   C   10  3
2   D   20  2
2   E   30  1
```